# Is there any function that avoids needing to print specific coefficient

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm trying to print a quadratic equation.
But if one of the coefficients is zero, then avoid print it and if one of them is 1, also print it without the number one.
I started to do it with if else but there are too much combinations.

```
double a, b, c;
printf("The quadratic equation is\n");

if (a == 0 && b != 0 && c != 0)
    printf("%.2lfX + %.2lf = 0\n", b, c);
else if (b == 0 && a != 0 && c != 0)
    printf("%.2lfX^2 + %.2lf = 0\n", a, c);
else if (c == 0 && a != 0 && b != 0)
    printf("%.2lfX^2 + %.2lfX = 0\n", a, b);
else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c !=0)
    printf("%.2lf = 0\n", c);
else if (b == 0 && c == 0 && a != 0)
    printf("%.2lfX^2 = 0\n", a);
else if (a == 0 && c == 0 && b != 0)
    printf("%.2lfX = 0\n", b);
else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0)
    printf("");
else if (a == 1 && b != 1 && c != 1) {
    printf("X^2 + %.2lfX + %.2lf = 0\n", b, c);
}
else if (b == 1 && a != 1 && c != 1) {
    printf("%.2lfX^2 + X + %.2lf = 0\n", a, c);
}
else if (c == 1 && a != 1 && b != 1) {
    printf("%.2lfX^2 + %.2lfX + 1 = 0\n", a, b);
}
else if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c != 1) {
    printf("X^2 + X + %.2lf = 0\n", c);
}
else if (b == 1 && c == 1 && a != 1) {
    printf("%.2lfX^2 + X + 1 = 0\n", a);
}
else if (a == 1 && c == 1 && b != 1) {
    printf("X^2 + %.2lfX + 1 = 0\n", b);
}
else if (a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1) {
    printf("X^2 + X + 1 = 0\n");
}
else {
    printf("%.2lfX^2 + %.2lfX + %.2lf = 0\n", a, b, c);
}
```

There must be a better way for doing it.
Now, I have to handle with cases like one of them is 0 and one of them is 1.

Please help me.
I'm trying to do it shorter.

Comment: Try to print only *one* term at a time.

Comment: You have reached a good moment to start using functions :-)

Comment: Your biggest problem here is the common beginner mistake of checking floating point numbers for equality.

Comment: Can you tell me what I have to do?

Comment: @Lundin, 0 and 1 are perfectly represented by `double` with no precision lost. It is fine check for equality in such cases. It is a problem when comparing against something like `1.3`.

Comment: @tstanisl It's not that simple, it depends on which calculation you obtained the numbers from. If the calculation cannot be exactly represented, the rounding error will be present in the result.

Comment: @Lundin, yes.. but saying that "checking floats for equality is a mistake" is an oversimplification. I agree that this check is error-prone but it still has some applications like the pretty-printer from the OP's question.

Comment: Instead of printing it all in one `printf`, try to break it into printing each of the parts alone. And the `\n` at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

You print each term in multiple parts with multiple `printf()` calls each. Make this into a function and you can easily extend it for larger equations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool printTerm(double coeff, int degree, bool isFirst) {
    // If this coefficient is 0, print nothing
    if (coeff == 0 && degree != 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // Handle minus sign
    if (coeff < 0) {
        printf(" - ");
    }
    // Print "+" only if some previous terms were printed
    else if (!isFirst) {
        printf(" + ");  
    }
    
    // Print the coefficient
    if (coeff != 1 || degree == 0) {
        // Minus sign was already printed, so fabs() is needed here
        printf("%.2lf", fabs(coeff));
    }
    
    // Print "X" and the degree
    if (degree >= 1) {
        printf("X");
        if (degree > 1) {
            printf("^%d", degree);
        }
    }
    
    // Return false if something was printed
    return false;
}

int main() {
    double a = 4.0, b = 1.0, c = 0.0;

    // Once printTerm returns false (something was printed), isFirst is set false
    bool isFirst = true;
    isFirst &= printTerm(a, 2, isFirst);
    isFirst &= printTerm(b, 1, isFirst);
    isFirst &= printTerm(c, 0, isFirst);
    printf(" = 0\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the terms separately after each other.  Be careful when comparing floating point numbers.  As mentioned in the comments, some floating point numbers are represented *exactly* for example 0.0 and 1.0 but others are not (so the comparison `a == 1.3` will not work as one might expect).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

double a = 1.0, b = 1.0, c = 1.0;

bool print_term(char *t, double coeff, bool needsign) {

    if (coeff != 0.0) {
        if (needsign && coeff > 0.0) {
            printf("+");
        }
        if (coeff != 1.0 || strcmp("", t) == 0) // also print c if it is 1.0
            printf("%.2lf%s", coeff, t);
        else
            printf("%s", t);
    }
    return coeff != 0.0;
}

int main() {
    bool need_operator = false;

    printf("The quadratic equation is\n");
    need_operator |= print_term("X^2", a, need_operator);
    need_operator |= print_term("X", b, need_operator);
    need_operator |= print_term("", c, need_operator);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Code tested with onlinegdb.com